# How can I handle a keyboard interrupt in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile like this. The `runall` target runs 2 submakes. When I press CTRL+C, the webserver is automatically stopped but the db docker container still stays up, and I have to manually call clean to stop it. Is there a way to detect it and call `clean` automatically?

```
.PHONY: runall # Runs DB and app
runall:
    $(MAKE) -j dbrun apprun

dbrun: # Spins up DB with docker compose up
    @echo "### Running DB"
    $(MAKE) -C store run 

apprun: # Spins up a webserver
    @echo "### Running app"
    $(MAKE) -C app run

.PHONY clean # stops the DB with docker compose down
clean:
    @echo "### Stopping DB"
    $(MAKE) -C store stop
```

Comment: Since you don't show us what the `run` commands in the `store` and `app` directories do it's impossible to say.  But in general as the dup question shows, the interrupt signal is passed to the command that make invokes.  If that command doesn't handle it, there's nothing make can do about it.